# instead of getting user input in console i need to get text in field username in webpage

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I need to get text in field username in webpage instead of getting user input in console, My Code:

```
 public void loginpage(){


        driver.findElement(By.id("Username")).clear();
        System.out.println("Username: ");
        Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input1 = scan1.nextLine();
        System.out.println(input1);

        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).clear();
        System.out.println("password: ");
        Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input2 = scan2.nextLine();


        Select drp= new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("AdminTypeId")));
        drp.selectByVisibleText("Super Admin");

        driver.findElement(By.id("login-submit")).click();
    }
```

Comment: Can you update us with the exact manual steps which you are trying to Automate?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `sendKeys()`

```
WebElement userName = driver.findElement(By.id("Username"));
userName.clear();
userName.sendKeys(input1);
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you need to get text from web page**

you have to use get commands.. say if need to get text from page then

```
driver.findElement(By.id("Username")).getText();
```

if need to get any attribute say value then

```
driver.findElement(By.id("Username")).getAttribute("value")
```

**If you need to input text to web page**

Then use sendkeys

```
driver.findElement(By.id("Username")).sendKeys("input text here");
```

Here in senkeys you can pass input1

```
driver.findElement(By.id("Username")).sendKeys(input1);
```

Comment: thank can u send me code in which we have to give login inputs through keyboard and those values are stored in website login page

Comment: driver.findElement(By.name("LoginText1")).clear();   
System.out.println("Username: ");    
Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);  
String input1 = scan1.nextLine();  
System.out.println(input1);                                                                        instead of it simply returning the user's input in to the console, is there a way to get it to insert it in to the text field. I want to insert it into a field which has the name LoginText1. This is for website testing with Selenium WebDriver.
I am new to Java and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: try this driver.findElement(By.name("LoginText1")).clear(); 
System.out.println("Username: "); 
Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in); 
String input1 = scan1.nextLine(); 
driver.findElement(By.name("LoginText1")).sendKeys(input1);